# Java different number of conditions inside a single IF statement

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have an algorithm required single `if` statement with different `&&` condition in each iteration. For example, let we have the following code:

```
int k = 0, d = 2;
if (arr[i] != b[0] && arr[i] != b[1]) {
    a[k] = arr[i];
    k = k + 1;
}
```

Here the number of conditions depend on `d` and `d` are selected randomly each time, that is if `d == 3`, then I need if statement to be as follows

```
if (arr[i] != b[0] && arr[i] != b[1] && arr[i] != b[2]) { ... }
```

also, if `d == 4` I need four conditions, and so on.

My code require this final step to be done. However, I couldn't solve this step yet, I will really grateful for any help.

Comment: Use a loop from 0 to `d`.  It cannot be done in a single `if` statement for arbitrary large `d`s.

Comment: You cannot change the number of conditions, it is static. But you can use functions to do the work for you: `if (checkArray(arr, b, d))` and then you make a loop in this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the array, and use a boolean variable to hold the result. Something like,

```
boolean val = true; 
for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
    if (arr[i] == b[j]) {
        val = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (val) {
    a[k] = arr[i];
    k = k + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
boolean isTrue(Object[] arr, int i, Object... b) { /* compare subarrays */ }

if( isTrue(arr, i, b) ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `d` is always the size of the `b` array, you could use

```
if (!Arrays.asList(b).contains(arr[i])) {
    // ...
}
```